# variable as button value in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, button, variables

I will be reading a tag from xml and assign it to a variable, ***ID***.

```
ID=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ID-NUM")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

How could I use the variable, ***ID***, as the button value to display?

```
document.write("<input type = button value = ID style='width:100'><br><br>");
```

Kindly let me know if I an not clear, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to put that variable into the string that you're writing out

```
document.write("<input type='button' value='" + ID + "' style='width:100%'/><br/><br/>");
```

Comment: Many thanks Russ, it worked. I will let you know if I have any issues, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you already have the button object written out, you can use the object model directly:

```
document.getElementById("idOfButtonObject").value = ID;
```

Comment: Many thanks EpicoxyMORON (nice sn), I did NOT have the button object. I will use this when needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write("<input type='button' value='" + ID + "' style='width:100;' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `document.write` to insert anything on the page. It's problematic because if you do it after the object model has been constructed, it will wipe out the entire document and create a new one. Instead use the DOM methods to create a button.

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'button';
input.value = ID; // set the ID
input.style = 'width: 100';
document.body.appendChild(input); // add to page
```

Comment: Many thanks Anurag, guess I will be ok with the document.write as of now. I will use the DOM method going forward.